# Propagate Data from Parent to Child Selection (D3)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have such an object, `data`, with which I want to create a selection.

```
var data = [
  {
    range: 30,
    color: 'blue',
  },
  {
    range: 50,
    color: 'red'
  }
];
```

So I do something like

```
var group = chart.selectAll('g')
  .data(data)
.enter().append('g');
```

Now I want to append a number of `circle` elements equal to `data['range']`.

```
var circle = group.selectAll('circle')
  .data(function(d) { return d3.extent(d.range); })
.enter().append('circle');
```

So here is my question, **what's the best practice for being able to access the data from the parent selection in its children.** For example, I want to access the `data['color']` in several attributes of `circle`.

Thus far, I've been using the `each()` to then apply the attribute to the `circle` element recursively

```
var circle = group.selectAll('circle')
  .data(function(d) { return d3.range(d.range); })
.enter().append('circle');

circle.each(function(d) {
    var parentData = this.parentNode.__data__;
    d3.select(this).attr('fill', function() { return parentData.color; });
});
```

Is there a more efficient practice for binding to the parent data, one that doesn't require use of `each()` and accessing the parent data via `this.parentNode.__data__`?

Comment: There are a few ways. However what you want to do is not clear. Since you are creating circles based on `d3.extent(d.range)`, which means you'll only create 2 circles - then which `color` do you want to get?

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say `d3.range(d.range)`, edits made.

I want the color to reflect the color specified in the parent data. If 30 `circle` elements are bound to the first object in `data`, I want to be able to easily access `data[0].color` in all of my `circle` elements. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the simplest way I guess is make an object which contains both the range value and color.

For example：

```
var circle = group.selectAll('circle')
  .data(function(d) { 
    return d3.range(d.range).map(function (rangeValue) {
      // returns an item that combines range value and color from parent data
      return {
        range: rangeValue,
        color: d.color
      };
    });
  })
.enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr('r', function (d) { return d.range; })
  .attr('fill', function (d) { return d.color; });
```